# how to check touch point is content on the edges of an curve path in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I am working with an app which is drawing curve between two boxes. Once its drawn that I want to change shape of curve using starting, ending and other point(touch point) if that is on the edge on curve.
So how can i check that touch point is on the edge  of my curve path or not?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your curve path must have an equation , am I right? 
You can simply check if the touch point is a solution of the equation.

You can also add a threshold by checking for each point of the rectangle R.
Where R is a rectangle centered in the touch point and of the size = your_threshold